# Bash IFS just for one

Tags: string, bash, split, ifs

Hey Guys i want to split a string into two seperate, e.g. resolution=1024x786 to width=1024 and height=786.
To do this, i found that code:

```
set -- "$resolution"
IFS="x"; declare -a coordinates=($*)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)
But now are all my Variables that contain an "x" in any position split there. How can use this "IFS" just for my $resolution?

Thanks for your Help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution

```
IFS=x read -r -a coordinates <<<"$resolution"
```

If you actually want the values in separate variables:

```
IFS=x read -r width height  <<<"$resolution"
```